# Surfacing query results from AWS RDS to public web page using Lambda, API Gateway and HTTP requests

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to implement an SQL querying interface for an AWS RDS MySQL database in a public web page. Ideally, a user will type a SQL query into a search field, press a "Query" button, and an API Gateway request will trigger a Lambda function to pull, return and print to the web page the relevant data from the database.

So far, I have the following Lambda function (which I am able to successfully test):

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const RDS = new AWS.RDSDataService()

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, 2))  // Log the entire event passed in

    // Get the sqlStatement string value
    // TODO: Implement a more secure way (e.g. "escaping") the string to avoid SQL injection
    var sqlStatement = event.sqlStatement;

    // The Lambda environment variables for the Aurora Cluster Arn, Database Name, and the AWS Secrets Arn hosting the master credentials of the serverless db
    var DBSecretsStoreArn = process.env.DBSecretsStoreArn;
    var DBAuroraClusterArn = process.env.DBAuroraClusterArn;
    var DatabaseName = process.env.DatabaseName;

    const params = {
      awsSecretStoreArn: DBSecretsStoreArn,
      dbClusterOrInstanceArn: DBAuroraClusterArn,
      sqlStatements: sqlStatement,
      database: DatabaseName
    }

    try {
      let dbResponse = await RDS.executeSql(params).promise()
      console.log(JSON.stringify(dbResponse, null, 2))

      var json_response = JSON.stringify(dbResponse)
      return json_response

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      return error
    }
}
```

This function, when tested with the following test format, returns a JSON blob I think.

Test event format:

```
{
  "sqlStatement": "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Name='JOHN DOE'"
}
```

Test event result:

```
..., {\"stringValue\":\"JOHN DOE\"},{\"stringValue\":\"2019-11-15\"},{\"stringValue\":\"AL\"},{\"stringValue\":\"1\"},{\"stringValue\":\"130\"},{\"stringValue\":\"Washington Co. Jail\"},{\"stringValue\":\"2019-10-31\"}, ...
```

I have the following API trigger details configured:

```
API endpoint: https://****************.amazonaws.com/prod/query
API Type: rest
Authorization: NONE
Method: POST
Resource path: /query
Stage: prod
```

I also have the following Lambda role configuration policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
                "rds:*",
                "rds-data:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The API, meanwhile, has the following methods/configurations:

[image]

[image]

Aside from any potential problems in this setup (i.e. the link between the Lambda and the API trigger and the formats of data passed/queried/returned), I need to figure out how to actually call this whole process from the click of a Query button. So, for example, the user would be on the page, type SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Name="JOHN DOE" into an HTML element, click an HTML button "Query", and the process would implement; then, the query result would populate in whatever format (to be simple, a messy string for now, but ideally eventually in a bootstrap DataTable) inside another HTML element.

I currently have a config.js file that contains:

```
window._config = {
    api: {
        invokeUrl: 'https://******************.amazonaws.com/prod',
    }
};
```

I also have a query.js file that contains a function (likely incorrect) attempt based on piecemeal tutorials online:

```
(function DisplayQuery($) {

    var query = document.getElementById("sql-placeholder").value;

    function passQuery(query) {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: _config.api.invokeUrl + '/query',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                sqlStatement: query
                }),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: document.getElementById("text-box").innerHTML = result.value,
            error: function ajaxError() {
                console.error('Error requesting ride');
            }
        })
    }
}(jQuery));
```

In my index.html file I have these search field and button elements:

```
<div class="active-cyan-4 mb-4">
   <input id="sql-placeholder" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Write SQL here..." aria-label="Search">
</div>
```

```
<div class="col-md-1">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="DisplayQuery()">Query</button>
</div>
```

Finally, this would be the test element where my string-format SQL query results would appear once they'd been returned by RDS --> Lambda --> API Gateway:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <p class= "test-box-class" id="test-box"><i>This is a test box for database query connection</i></p>
</div>
```

This is a lot perhaps, but I'm wondering if anyone has any insight into how to make this process run, at least well enough so that hitting the Query button returns something to the web page.

Comment: you have detailed everything well. I can't see anything missing. are you facing any issues.

Comment: My primary issue is that upon clicking the button to initiate the process, nothing seems to be happening @ArunmainthanKamalanathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following @antonku's answer, The reason for the "Missing Authentication Token" error was, you are trying to access a "POST" http method in the browser, The browser requests URL using the "GET" http method.

You may also get the same error message when the URL is incorrect.

Add some console.log statements to see the api response in the front end

```
var DisplayQuery;
(function($) {
  DisplayQuery = function() {
    $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: _config.api.invokeUrl + '/query',
      data: $('#sql-placeholder').val(),
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function(response) {
        console.log('response: ', response);
        $('#test-box').text(JSON.stringify(response))
      },
      error: function ajaxError(error) {
        console.error('Error requesting ride');
      }
    })
  }
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Thank you -- I created a GET method within the API Gateway console -- when I redeploy and click Invoke URL it opens https://************.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod with the same message regarding missing authentication token... I don't believe the URL is incorrect since I clicked it directly from the console where it was generated.

Comment: Follow up: when I try to go to the URL for the /query specifically (https://**********.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/query), I get the message ```{"message": "Internal server error"}```

Comment: If you get internal server error, It means you are acessing the URL correctly but your api endpoint has encountered some errors while processing your request. That should be ok because you are not passing the data it requires when opening  the url on the browser?

Comment: That makes sense... but when I try to press the button on the web page there is no activity... is there something additional I need to configure within the API/resource/method? I have very little experience with this process.

Comment: No your configuration seems fine to me. What you can do is you can test the API from the API gateway console itself using the test button on the top left of your second screenshot. You can pass the data to the test like `{ "sqlStatement": "[your query]" }`. Also add a console.log to print the sqlStatement inside the API to see whats api receives.

Comment: That was helpful, thank you -- using the Test button with Query String {"sqlStatement": "SELECT * FROM Table"} the console includes: ```Sat Nov 30 17:21:56 UTC 2019 : Endpoint response body before transformations: {"message":"Missing required key 'sqlStatements' in params","code":"MissingRequiredParameter","time":"2019-11-30T17:21:56.065Z"}
Sat Nov 30 17:21:56 UTC 2019 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response
Sat Nov 30 17:21:56 UTC 2019 : Method completed with status: 502```

Comment: good. i think thats because `event.sqlStatement` not working. do `console.log(event)` to see whats in the event.

Comment: Apologies... do I add console.log(event) within the Lambda Function or somewhere within the Test in the API Gateway?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203392/discussion-between-arunmainthan-kamalanathan-and-ojt).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with the code that makes the ajax request.

- On button click `DisplayQuery` is called, however this name is used for the function that is immediately invoked on the initial page load. Instead on the button click you need to invoke the function that sends the ajax request.
- The is also no need to `JSON.stringify` the input value since it's already a string.
- Also, for the `success` key, it's required to provide a function that accepts the response.

Changing `query.js` in the following way should resolve these concerns:

```
var DisplayQuery;
(function($) {
  DisplayQuery = function() {
    $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: _config.api.invokeUrl + '/query',
      data: $('#sql-placeholder').val(),
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function(response) {
        $('#test-box').text(JSON.stringify(response))
      },
      error: function ajaxError() {
        console.error('Error requesting ride');
      }
    })
  }
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply -- I've updated query.js with your code -- when I try to type a query into the #sql-placeholder field and press the button to initiate the process, nothing seems to be happening...

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant as well, but I just opened the API URL (https://*********************.amazonaws.com/prod/query) and I see the following: ```{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}```

Comment: Add a `console.log` statement for the success as well, because you can see the response in the browser console. modified my answer above to add code